# JQuery image resizer and text manipulator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was any sort of way of making a text and image manipulator just in Javascript and JQuery or will I need to use Flash. Im only asking if it is possible, a demo of one made in flash : http://www.tweak.com/business-card-brochures-a4-tri-fold.html?tweak_id=fs000080000itn6kgvog000000&productSetId=fs000080000itn6kgtl0000000&image=http://preview.tweak.com/media/previews/560000_564999/fs000080000itn6kgvog000000/preview.jpg , click on personalize and you can see the features like text resizing, image adding and really easy movement of all objects on the preview.

Comment: You can probably accomplish something like this through Javascript plugins, but it depends on what you mean exactly by "image manipulation" and "image adding".  
With respect to the link that you posted, I don't think it would be easy to make something like that solely using Javascript/jQuery plugins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. It would take some work though, that's a pretty involved application.

Take a look at this site to get an idea:
[JS/HTML5 Image Editor Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-image-editor-with-easeljs-jquery-and-the-html5-file-api--active-11142)

Hope that helps :)
-Ted

Comment: This looks really good! Thanks a lot :) The one i'll  be making probably wont be as feature rich .

Comment: Sure thing. That is a pretty cool tutorial, I think I'm going to lose a few hours to messing around with it :)